# How to run emacs daemon as a systemd service with Wayland on Ubuntu 22.04+?

Tags: 22.04, systemd, wayland, emacs, 23.10

The stock systemd user service file for emacs 29.1 looks something like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Emacs text editor
Documentation=info:emacs man:emacs(1) https://gnu.org/software/emacs/

[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/bin/emacs --fg-daemon
# ExecStop=/usr/bin/emacsclient --eval "(kill-emacs)"

# Emacs will exit with status 15 after having received SIGTERM, which
# is the default "KillSignal" value systemd uses to stop services.
SuccessExitStatus=15

# The location of the SSH auth socket varies by distribution, and some
# set it from PAM, so don't override by default.
# Environment=SSH_AUTH_SOCK=%t/keyring/ssh
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

However, after my computer starts up and I login, and try to run `emacsclient -c`, nothing happens and `journalctl -u emacs -f --user` contains an error log:

> Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified

After a restart of emacs (`systemctl --user restart emacs`), there is no problem in starting emacs, and the emacsclient window opens up as expected. However, after a reboot, the same problem happens - clearly having to restart emacs immediately up login defeats the purpose of setting it up as a systemd user service.

After various googling, I ended up on https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon#h5o-19 (**EDIT 1**: this link is now dead, see bottom) which says that we need to ensure emacs is started up after Gnome by adding these lines:

```
[Unit]
Requires=org.gnome.Shell@wayland.service
After=org.gnome.Shell@wayland.service
```

The problem is that Ubuntu 22.04+ (currently running 23.10) does not have a org.gnome.Shell@wayland.service unit. I've tried various things like `gdm.service`, `user@%U.service` instead of gnome shell in the above section and nothing seems to work. What's the right way here?

I've also had a look at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/74937/systemd-starts-emacs-daemon-without-xauthority-environment-variable-after-upgrad that mentions the same problem on gnome/x11/fedora with a slightly different solution, but that doesn't work for Gnome/Wayland/Ubuntu combination.

I've also asked this question in the [Emacs StackExchange](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/79985/how-to-run-emacs-as-a-systemd-service-with-wayland-on-ubuntu-22-04?noredirect=1#comment134151_79985) and have been redirected here.

**EDIT 1:**

Emacs Wiki has updated the instructions so that the link above is dead. Updated instructions are (as of this writing) at https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon#h5o-1

However, these instructions do not work on Ubuntu 23.10 as well. I still get the same error log as above when starting `emacsclient -c` after a reboot (yes I did a `daemon-reload` too). Adding a drop-in with:

```
[Unit]
After=graphical-session.target
```

did not help.

Comment: I'm curious that you don't have a `org.gnome.Shell@wayland.service` service file - it seems to be in the [gnome-shell-common filelist](https://packages.ubuntu.com/mantic/all/gnome-shell-common/filelist)

Comment: I see it installed on my system but the unit does not seem to be "active" - 

`sudo systemctl status org.gnome.Shell@wayland.service`
gives `Unit org.gnome.Shell@wayland.service could not be found.`

Comment: ... it would be a user unit, so try `systemctl status --user org.gnome.Shell@wayland.service`

Comment: Thank you, that helped me find the unit, but it didn't solve the original problem. I still have the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

What helps, in addition to setting:

```ini
[Unit]
After=graphical-session.target

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical-session.target
```

is to move the config file from the symlink `~/.config/systemd/user/default.target.wants/emacs.service` (pointing to `/usr/lib/systemd/user/emacs.service`) to a new directory, `graphical-session.target.wants`.

So now it should be:

```
~/.config/systemd/user/graphical-session.target.wants/emacs.service -> /usr/lib/systemd/user/emacs.service
```